# Which wavelengths are assigned to which bands in NAIP imagery?

Tags: image

I cannot seem to find a definitive source on which wavelengths are assigned to which bands for 4-band NAIP imagery.  [Here is an example](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/) of the imagery I am working with (2011 4-band NAIP imagery).  I contacted the [USDA FSA APFO Aerial Photography Field Office](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/FSA/apfoapp?area=apfohome&subject=landing&topic=landing) who then sent me a metadata file.  The only pertinent information in the metadata is as follows:

> ```
>                 Each sensor collected 11 image bands.
>
>                 PanF27A,PanF02A and PanB14A panchromatic bands with a
>
>                 spectral range of 465-676nm. RedN00a and RedB16a with a
>
>                 spectral range of 604-664nm. GrnN00a and GrnB16a with a
>
>                 spectral range of 533-587nm. BluN00a and BluB16a with a
>
>                 spectral range of 420-492nm and Near-infrared bands
>
>                 NirN00a and NirB16a with a spectral range of 833-920nm.
>
>                 The CCD arrays have a pixel size of 6.5 microns in a
>
>                 12000x1 format.
> ```

When analyzing the pixel brightness values for water, band 1 appears to be red due to lower pixel brightness values and band 3 appears to be blue due to high pixel brightness values and band 4 is definitely nIR due to very low pixel brightness values.

**Is there a definitive source to support or reject my assumptions on which bands are which?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with a NAIP representative that sent me the following info sheet for NAIP sensors - apparently the range is 675 - 940 um, but depends on the sensor that collected the image. Here is the info sheet I received.[image]

Answer (score 1):

(I had multiple links, but stackexchange says I don't have enough reputation points.)

This is link is more "definitive" for your 2011 time frame (see 3rd paragraph). https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/NAIP

NAIP:

Band 1 is Visible Red

Band 2 is Visible Green

Band 3 is Visible Blue

Band 4 is NIR

Bands 1 & 3 are flipped flopped compared to traditional remote sensing satellites like QuickBird, Ikonos and Landsat 4/5.  This is important if you are calculating vegetation indices that uses the visible Red.  You have to be sure you properly specify the Red band, which for NAIP is band 1 (and not band 3).

The last several years an Leica ADS 80 or ADS 100 sensor has been used.
The very last slide in this Leica USDA presentation may help: (Google NAIP ADS 80 100 to find the presentation.)

I see you're using ERDAS.  I have a lot of experience with ERDAS and NAIP.  With the image open in the viewer, select the Multispectral tab. In the middle of the tool bar there is a "Choose Sensor".  Select the NAIP RGBN from the drop down menu.  Then right below that, you can select False Color IR or True Color for the display you desire.

Comment: Here is the ADS sensor slide for wavelengths.  See the very last slide https://www.fsa.usda.gov/Internet/FSA_File/3_ads80naippres.pdf[![enter image description here][1]][1]